# Java String.split with varied character format

Tags: java, regex, string

I have strings of the following format

`(1, 3, value)`

I want to split this string using String.split so that I can get the three values without the delemeters. I want the output to look like

```
1
3
value
```

The problem is that the value sometimes contains delimeter values itself, such as the string `revolution_(1848)`

How can I do this with String.split(), so that I can split the words based on commas and inside the brackets, so I get only the three values.

Thanks.

Comment: The delimiter here is a comma, not a bracket. Can you assume there will be no commas in the value? If so: remove the brackets and split on the comma.

Comment: I didn't see `split(",")` doesn't work here.

Comment: Use `String.split(",")` then you can manually remove the `(` & `)` from the first and last elements (that's _if_ your string really comes inside of parens). **Edit** Quincunx also has a similar solution that removes the parens _before_ splitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the parentheses are always on the outside, just don't consider them and split on the `,`s:

```
String toSplit = "(1, 3, value, revolution_(1848))";
toSplit = toSplit.substring(1,toSplit.length() - 1); //ignore wrapping characters.
String[] splitted = toSplit.split(",");
```